# crontab cannot find environment variable even after sourcing .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, cron, environment-variables, source

```
crontab -e
```

```
00 00 * * * /home/username/run.sh >> /home/username/log 2>&1
```

Inside run.sh:

```
source /home/username/.bashrc
java
```

When crontab job is triggered, I got this error in the log:

```
/home/username/run.sh: 1: /home/username/run.sh: java: not found
```

However, java path is set in /home/username/.bashrc, so I was expecting sourcing should set the java path:

I know I can fix it by:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_231/bin:$PATH"
java
```

But why sourcing .bashrc is not enough? What environment variables does crontab have exactly and what does source .bashrc do exactly (so that crontab doesn't take it into account)?

Thanks.

Comment: either put the absolute PATH of java in your script, or set the PATH on the crontab entry itself.  see `man 5 crontab`

Comment: What distro or flavor of linux are you using? does /home/username/.bashrc have an interactivity check (`case $- in` ... for example)?

Comment: Add /home/username/.bashrc to your question.

Comment: `cron` executes scripts usually with `sh`. `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: @Cyrus that was my first thought as well - but I'd expect `sh` to have barfed on the `source` command (which is a bashism for the POSIX `.` I think?)

Comment: @steeldriver: yes, my `sh` knows nothing about `source`. I suggest to add a shebang with `bash` in `/home/username/run.sh` or run `/home/username/run.sh` with `bash`.

Comment: `sh` should recognize `source` as it's a shell builtin for `sh` (as well as `bash`).

Comment: @NasirRiley Only if the `/bin/sh` executable is `bash` in disguise. If it's `dash`, it will not understand `source` and you'll get `source: not found`.  The `source` comand is simply not standard, so don't expect `/bin/sh` to know about it. Use `.` (dot) instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda Not only that, but `.` in `dash` won't even recognize the file to be sourced unless the full path is used(unless it's just me).

Comment: @NasirRiley It;s not just you, but the filename doesn't have to be an absolute path.  If the filename after `.` is a plain filename, `dash` looks for the file on `$PATH`.  So if you want to source a local file, specify a relative or absolute pathname to that file; do `. ./.mydashrc` instead of `. .mydashrc`.  `bash` does the same thing, except that in non-POSIX mode it also looks in the current directory if it doesn't find a match on `$PATH`. And `bash` lets you turn off the `$PATH` search by doing `shopt -u sourcepath`.

Answer (score 0):

I have some guessing but may be wrong:

- when we open a bash shell, we start a bash process, and when running .bashrc, it makes change to the environment of this bash process only
- crontab has its own process that has no relation to the bash process opened
- when sourcing .bashrc, it only makes changes to bash process (though there's none when running crontab??), therefore crontab still
  does not have any change to the environment variable

Therefore, sourcing .bashrc doesn't help crontab.